# Excel SUMPRODUCT and MMULT with condition

Tags: excel

Hello I need to make a `sumproduct` with general conditions.
The correct values is shown in cell `B6`, `B7` and `B8`

In cell `B6` I have this formula `=A1*A2+B1*B2+C1*C2` to understand what is the result that I expected.
In `B7` is `=D1*D2+E1*E2` and so on...

[image]

I've tried with this formula `=SUMPRODUCT(A3:G3=A6,A1:G1,A2:G2)` in cell `B6` but the result is 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `=SUMPRODUCT(1*(A3:G3=A6),A1:G1,A2:G2)` in cell `B6`.

Better still use `=SUMPRODUCT(1*(A$3:G$3=A6),A$1:G$1,A$2:G$2)`

and you will be able to copy the formula from `B6` to `B7:B8` and it will behave as you want.

Answer (score 1):

From [this page](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-sumproduct-function), I learned that "--" can transform True and False values into 1's and 0's.

That's probably why you are getting 0, the formula you use adds boolean values to numerical values.

So the formula you are looking for in cell B6 is `=SUMPRODUCT(--(A3:G3=A6),A1:G1,A2:G2)`.

Tested on Excel 2010, it worked.